# Reflection issue in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

I am having an issue porting a WP7 app to a win8 store app...

I run this code to populate fields from elements inside XML file:

```
Venue lv = new Venue();

            foreach (var t in Fields)
            {
                foreach (var f in t.Elements())
                {
                    lv.SaveData(f.Attribute("name").Value, f.Value, lv);
                }
            }
```

Data class:

```
 public class Venue //: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string authority { get; set; }
        public string organisation { get; set; }
        public string control_type { get; set; }
    }
```

Run SaveData Method:

```
public void SaveData(string field, string value, Venue v)
        {

            foreach (MemberInfo mi in v.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetMembers())
            {
                if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;

                    if (pi.Name == "Coordinate")
                        continue;

                    if (pi.Name == field)
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(v, value, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue is, the GetMembers definition does not exist in WinRT, so either need to find an alternative to expose the same proeprties, or have to find a way to rewrite the system.

I did not write this piece of code myself, but I can just about understand what it is doing. I am not too familar on reflection, apart from the basic introductions I have just read
Any quick fixes

Comment: Have you tried `GetType().GetMembers()` (not using `GetTypeInfo`) ?

Comment: Hi, yes, it does not exist either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetType` is an extension method. You need to include the reflection namespace:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

For your `SaveData` method, you can do something like:

```
public void SaveData(string field, string value, Venue v)
{
    var typeinfo = v.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
    var pi = typeinfo.GetDeclaredProperty(field);

    if (pi != null && pi.Name != "Coordinate")
       pi.SetValue(v, value);
}
```

You probably want to do some better error checking than the code above. For example making sure `v` and `pi.Name` are not null.

Comment: This seems to be it! Very easy!